# Moving average divided by moving average

Tags: r, spotfire, terr

I know that we can use inbuild function **“Moving Average”** to calculate rolling average with specific intervals like 3 months, 12 months, etc.. Is it possible to divide two moving average values to get the “Per system value”.

For example:

Moving average 1: Total number of Hrs 
Moving average 2: Total number of systems

Per System = Total number of Hrs/ Total number of systems

Appreciate your help and suggestions.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please use `dput()` to present your data.

Comment: @jogo Thanks. I tried creating a calculated column to calculate the moving average by using a case statement to limit the period but it didn’t turn up well.

Comment: Please show your code and your data, i.e. edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43253870/edit . Please read [ask] and [mcve] and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example In the current form your question is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Are you trying to use TERR for this or Spotfire built in functions?

Comment: @scsimon Thanks. I was trying in both ways. I found a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

1. Create a simple calculated column using **"OVER" & "Intersect"**  function to calculate the **Moving Average** . 
   For example:  `SUM([Total number of Hrs) OVER (Intersect(LastPeriods(12,[Yr_Mn]),[XXX])) / 12`"

Also use the same logic to calculate moving average for Total number of systems.

2. In the visualization, using **"First"**  function, exclude the duplicates.
   For example:

   `First([Total number of Hrs]) / First([Total number of systems] as [Per System Value]`